# htaccess rewrite mod Needs to ending slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using htaccess rewrite mod to rewrite urls.

Now, i have simple question!

this is my htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/ index.php?name=$1  [L]
```

And my php index.php :

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
$get = ($_GET['name']);
} else {
    echo "null";
}
?>
```

Now,

If i open this url :

```
http://exmaple.com/myname/
```

It will work!

But If i open this one : (without ending slash)

```
http://exmaple.com/myname
```

It doesn't work.

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess should be like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(/)?$ index.php?name=$1  [L]
```

Comment: Not Worked! the `name` is not understanding in php.